# How can run JavaScript code for all users at the same time and display the same generated numbers for all users

Tags: javascript, real-time

I have a big problem in my site.

I have in my site a page to generate a random numbers with Spinning Wheel in Javascript.

Code of generating numbers:

```
function chooseNumbers ()
{
    const wheel = document.querySelector('.circle');

    let deg = 0;

    deg = Math.floor((Math.random() * (360 - 1) + 1));
    wheel.style.transition = 'all 10s ease-out';
    wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;

    /**
     * Circle height: 830px
     * Circle width: 830px
     * angle: 36deg
     * 
     * if deg result between this numbers
     * 
     * 0   => 36  = 1
     * 36  => 72  = 2
     * 72  => 108 = 3
     * 108 => 144 = 4
     * 144 => 180 = 5
     * 180 => 216 = 6
     * 216 => 252 = 7
     * 252 => 288 = 8
     * 288 => 324 = 9
     * 324 => 360 = 0
     * 
     * pi = c / d
     */
}
```

I need to display on my users "IN THE SAME TIME" how the page generate the numbers and how the Spinning Wheel choose the numbers.

That's mean I need to run the same Javascript Code and show the same results to all existing users.

If the page runs JavaScript code for every user
It will show different results for each user because I use

```
Math.random()
```

to generate the random number.

So I need a way to display the wheel spin to all users at the same time and display the same results that the code generates in JavaScript.

What is the necessary technique to do this method?

Comment: Is this client-side JS?

Comment: @andrbrue It would appear so, he's using `document.querySelector`

Comment: So, I guess you need to set up a server as your clients need to have a way of communicating. You cannot solve this using simple only client-side JS.

Comment: i think i need server side to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database for this. Theres free ones that you could use to try.
The working principle would be, with a different page, in javascript you generate various random numbers and their hour for them to be displayed and then you upload them using PHP to your database. That would be called your backend which is the part the user never gets to see. Now, for each user to see those numbers, you would start the spinning wheel and get the number from the database with PHP too, and then make the wheel stop at that number, in that way it'll the same number for each user and the wheel will keep as long as you keep adding numbers to your database

Comment: That mean  
first when i need to generate the numbers. i should send ajax request to function in php to generate number and return this number to wheel to display it??

Comment: the question is how can i generate the same number `deg = Math.floor((Math.random() * (360 - 1) + 1));` in php

Comment: You can use $MyRandNum =  mt_rand()*(360-1)+1

Comment: No problem bud!!

Comment: bro I am sorry but I want to ask you a question.
we know Javascript run on user browser on visitor browser.

Comment: bro I am sorry but I want to ask you a question.
we know Javascript run on user browser on visitor browser.
that mean the Javascript code run when the user open the page in my site.
My idea is: 
I have products on my site and each product have cards. When the users buy all cards i set in my database the time() plus 24 hours to make the draw on the winner card. 
The problem is: what happen if no users exists in product page to see the draw??
that mean the wheel function will not working and not generate the winner card?
how can make site generate the numbers auto when the time is come?

Comment: When purchasing the last card in the product
The time is saved plus 24 hours in order for the card to be withdrawn after 24 hours.
Then a countdown timer will appear. When the time reaches 0: 0, the wheel’s function will be triggered to generate the card number. And all this work with Javascript code.
The problem is that JavaScript does not work automatically unless there is a visitor watching the countdown. What will happen if no visitor sees the countdown. This means that the code will not generate the winning card.

Comment: How can I make the website generate the numbers at the required time
Even if no visitor is on the site

Comment: Hey Hassan! Sorry for the late reply. Well, for that, when you generate the number and upload to database, you could also generate a time for when you want that number to be displayed so, when user gets into the page, its javascript read the number in database and also the time and you gotta make a javascript code that will make the wheel spin.  if the time that you set for that number is still early, the wheel spins, if not the wheel would be stopped